# input() causes unexpected EOF SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have written a return function for my group project.
I am using python 3.4 and wrote this:

```
def readrouter(x, y):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE
                     function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x, y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

a = input("x:")
b = input("y:")
for result in readrouter(a,b):
    print (result[0])
```

As my major member is using 2.7 and I need to follow his version now.
After I re-input my .py into python 2.7
there is a error:

```
x:create vlan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/f0449492/Desktop/2015225/database.py", line 322, in <module>
    a = input("x")
  File "<string>", line 1
    create vlan
             ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Process finished with exit code 1
```

how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.7, replace [*input()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) with [*raw_input()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input).

The former runs [*eval()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval) on the input string and expects valid Python code as input.  Your input `create vlan` isn't valid Python and can't be eval'ed.  The latter just returns a string with no further processing.

Comment: Omg, thank you but I should not ask this stupid question

Comment: It's OK, you're probably not the first person to have tripped over this. Having this answer out in the wild will at least reduce the odds of others going through the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up - to ensure compatibility with both Python branches you may use [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) .